# How can we split super Java String to sub String alone?

Tags: java, string

eg:

`superpath = /path/to/a/b/c/d`

How can we split *superpath* to

> subpath1 = /path/to/a
>
> subpath2 = /path/to/a/b
>
> subpath3 = /path/to/a/b/c
>
> subpath = /path/to/a/b/c/d

sorry for not clarity about this question.

What's my question is:**is there one method to do this?**,do not split、and append again. like below:

`String superpath = "/path/to/a/b/c/d"
 String [] subStrList = superPath.someMethod(somePar);
 //subStrList[i] equals "/path/to/a"`

I know , I can use the `split` method to split String step by step, I have searched Google and official Java docs, I can't find a API interface to do this ,so I posted a question here . may be somebody misunderstand my intent。

My

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
        String str = "/path/to/a/b/c/d";
        String[] strArray= str.split("/");
        String temp = "";
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=1; i<strArray.length; i++){
            temp = temp + "/" + strArray[i];
            arrayList.add(temp);
        }
```

here arrayList consists of all sub paths

Comment: While this answer might indeed solve the issue you could greatly improve the quality of the answer by also explaining your approach. That is especially helpful if beginners visit this question and read your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
String[] array = superPath.replace("/path/to/" , "").split('/');
List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
for(String item : array)
{
  temp = temp + "/" + item;
  paths.add("/path/to" + temp);  
}
```

Comment: While this answer might indeed solve the issue you could greatly improve the quality of the answer by also explaining your approach. That is especially helpful if beginners visit this question and read your answer.